# Zend framework 2 configuration uses

Tags: version-control, zend-framework2, zend-config

I would  like know what's the difference between the uses of global.php and local.php files.
In the [Zend documentation](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html), these files only register the database configuration, but I don't understand because the credentials are in a separated file (local.php).

Zend documentation talks about a version control system (VCS), but I don't understand because if these files are in a same directory, they don't have the same visibility inside VCS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The idea they work with, is (in git terms) an *ignore*. If you watch the git repository for the Skeleton Application, you see there is a [.gitignore](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/config/autoload/.gitignore) file in that directory.

This means, if you use git as a VCS, all files **except** any file matching `local.php` or `*.local.php` will be commited into the VCS. Therefore, the `local.php` but also the `my-foo.local.php` files will be kept outside the VCS.

This is very useful for local configuration (e.g. you want to turn the cache off on your development machine) or credentials (database, email or api keys for 3rd party services). The content of the local config files can be stored or communicated via other means.

To answer your question: yes, they are in the same directory, but they are ignored for the VCS. If you work with svn, there is also a term called [svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3) and other VCSes have similar features.